# Find nth row per group in a large dataset with Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, partitioning

I have a (very) large dataset partitioned by `year`, `month` and `day`. The partition columns were derived from a `updated_at` column during ingestion. Here is how it looks like:

| id | user | updated_at | year | month | day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 1992-01-19 | 1992 | 1 | 19 |
| 2 | c | 1992-01-20 | 1992 | 1 | 20 |
| 3 | a | 1992-01-21 | 1992 | 1 | 21 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 720987 | c | 2012-07-20 | 2012 | 7 | 20 |
| 720988 | a | 2012-07-21 | 2012 | 7 | 21 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

I need to use Apache Spark to find the **5th earliest event per user**.

A simple window function like the one below is impossible since I use a shared cluster and I won't have enough resources to do in-memory processing at any given time due to the size of the dataset.

```py
window = Window.partitionBy("user").orderBy(F.asc("updated_at"))
```

```py
.withColumn("rank", F.dense_rank().over(window))
.filter(F.col("rank") == 5)
```

I am considering looping through partitions, processing and persisting data to disk, and then merging them back. How would you solve it? Thanks!

Comment: If you want to have the nth of each user so you better have the dataset repartitioned (re-shuffled) by user first, so rows of the same user will be on the same machine. Only then apply the window.

Comment: We were discussing the possibility to keep two versions of the data, one partitioned by date as the question, and the other partitioned by user. The storage cost may be lower than shuffling data in every job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the code below will be faster because data is partitioned by these cols and spark can benefit from data locality.

```
Window.partitionBy("user").orderBy(F.asc("year"), F.asc("month"), F.asc("day"))
```